# Duda c# javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hasta ahora para hacer un **login** utilizando una base de datos para verificarlo , lo que hacia, era que con `javascript` validaba la información de formulario,
para luego enviar los datos, los cuales mediante php, hacia una consulta a la base de datos, que corroborara los datos introducidos por el usuario, con los almacenados en la base de datos.

Pero ahora usando `ASP`, he creado un login mediante el cuadro de herramientas que crea objetos `<asp:button>` y elementos de este estilo con `c#`, luego he creado la conexión a la base de datos, para recoger la respuesta de la consulta a la base de datos, y finalmente, he verificado que los datos de la base de datos fueran iguales a los que introdujo el usuario en el login.

El código que he usado es algo similar a esto:

```
Usuario usu1=new Usuario();

//el email y el password serian los 2 textbox que he creado para que el cliente introduzca los datos
if (usu1.Login==this.Email.Text&&usu1.Password==this.Password.Text){

    //y ahora el codigo que nos llevaria  a la pagina web de los usuarios correctos
}
```

Y mi pregunta es:

Al utilizar `ASP` no me ha hecho falta utilizar `javascript` para nada, ya que lo he hecho todo con `c#`. Esto estaría bien hecho?, ya que me funciona correctamente y si está bien hecho como es que no me hace falta utilizar `javascript`?

Ya que tengo entendido que `javascript` es para programar en el cliente y `c#` sería un lenguaje para programar en el servidor.

Comment: Disculpa, te recomiendo cambiar tu titulo, ya que no especifica cual es tu duda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los controles de `asp.net` la maryoria corren del lado del `server`, es por eso que no necesitas `javascript`, y en `asp` tienes dos archivos el `.aspx` y el `.cs`, el aspx tiene el código HTML y el .cs tiene el code behind.

Anexo texto de la siguiente liga:

[Tutorial ASP.NET: Utilización de código detrás del modelo o código en línea](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/tutorial-asp-net-utilizacion-de-codigo-modelo-codigo-en-linea/)

> Nuestro ejemplo tendrá dos archivos:
>
> 1. Default.aspx
> 2. Default.cs
>
> Default.aspx: Incluirá todo lo relacionado con interfaz de usuario.
>
> Default.cs: Aquí pondremos el código de los eventos que se ejecuten
>   desde el formulario.

Como lo indica la explicación anterior, en `asp.net` el archivo `.aspx` es solo la interfaz de usuario y el archivo `.cs` que esta en `c#` es donde se programan los eventos de la interfaz, más parecido a la programación para `windows`.  En el caso de `PHP` y otros lenguajes no existe el `code behind` tal vez por eso te parece ilógico.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas JavaScript, siendo estrictos tampoco lo necesitarias con PHP, los datos del 'form' se envian automaticamente con un 'input' tipo 'submit', solo necesitarias JavaScript si quisieras hacer tu llamado al servidor con AJAX. Ahora ASP.NET genera bastante codigo JavaScript para aligerar el tiempo de produccion (aunque en ocaciones el tiempo de ejecucion se ve afectado), por ejemplo puede generar codigo para hacer llamadas asincronas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer con javascript en el lado del cliente lo puedes hacer con C# en el lado del servidor y da los mismos resultados, solo que hay situaciones en que hacer consultas sencillas al servidor no es factible por que esto puede ocasionar lentitud el hacer tantas llamadas al servidor, toma en cuenta que en un servidor hay miles y miles de consultas cada segundo.

Para validaciones usa javascript o puedes usar los validator que ya tiene asp.net, búscalos en la barra de heramientas.

Answer (score 0):

**>>Al utilizar ASP no me ha hecho falta utilizar javascript para nada, ya que lo he hecho todo con c#. Esto estaría bien hecho?**

Lo que no logro visualizar en el codigo que has implementado es en que punto accedes a la db para validar el usuario y password

Alli solo instancias una clase usuario y defines un if, con solo eso no alcanza para validar contra una db, necesitas usar ado.net

Mas alla de este punto el resto es correcto

**>>ya que me funciona correctamente y si está bien hecho como es que no me hace falta utilizar javascript?**

No necesitas javascript porque realizas un submit al servidor haciendo uso de los eventos de los controles de asp.net

Distinto seria si quieres implementar esto mismo sin que se refresque el form, en ese caso deberias usar javascript con jquery he invocar un WebMethod del lado del servidor, en este caso los eventos no aplicarian, salvo que uses el control UpdatePanel

Nota: en php no es obligatorio usar javascript para implementar lo que planteas